# Show total channel entries with matrix

Tags: matrix

I am looking to show the total number of channel entries which do not have and empty matrix field.

For example I have entries which have a matrix field with customer information. I would like, if possible, to show all the channel entries which have no customer information added.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks
Ben

Comment: Updated my answer to include another option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use the [**search:field_name**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#search-field-name) parameter on your Channel Entries tag. You can use it like...

```
search:your_matrix_field="not IS_EMPTY"
```

...and it will only return entries that actually have content in your Matrix field.

---

Alternatively, Adrian Macneil just released a nifty plugin called [**Channel Query**](https://github.com/expressodev/channel_query) that is perfect for this. It works just like the Channel Entries tag but allows you to specify a custom query to get just the entry_ids you need. So in this case you'd select entries where your Matrix field is not empty.

This will loop over all the entries that have Matrix data:

```
{exp:channel_query sql="SELECT entry_id FROM exp_channel_data WHERE field_id_22 != '' AND channel_id = '12'"}
    {title}<br>
{/exp:channel_query}
```

Substitute the field_id for your Matrix field's id and channel_id for your particular Channel.

---

**If instead you want only the total results** you can just use the [Query module](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/query/):

```
{exp:query sql=
    "SELECT COUNT(exp_channel_data.entry_id) AS total
    FROM exp_channel_data
    JOIN exp_channel_titles
    ON exp_channel_titles.entry_id = exp_channel_data.entry_id
    WHERE field_id_22 != ''
    AND status = 'open'
    AND exp_channel_data.channel_id = '12'"
}
    {total}
{/exp:query}
```

For either of these queries you can change to showing/counting only entries that *do not* have any Matrix data by altering the `field_id_X != ''` to `field_id_X = ''`

Comment: That pretty much covers every angle. :)

Comment: I need to limit this from one channel only which has a channel_id is 10.I tried adding WHERE channel_id ='10' but I get SQL errors.

Comment: Since there is already `WHERE` clause you need to add any additional conditions immediately after that by using `AND`. So for example `WHERE field_id_22 != '' AND channel_id = '10'`

Comment: Thanks Alex, when I add the AND channel_id = '10' after the WHERE clause I get the following: "Column 'channel_id' in where clause is ambiguous"

Comment: Ah, OK, in that case it's because both exp_channel_title and exp_channel_data both have a channel_id field, so just specify a table for channel_id so it isn't ambiguous. Like this: `WHERE field_id_22 = ''AND exp_channel_data.channel_id = '12'`. I will update my answer.